# Show content of another file in org-column view

Tags: org-mode

I want to have something like:

```
* The column view
:PROPERTIES:
:Other_file_content: file:<path-to-file/file.org>::*Heading
:END:
```

and then display in the column view in the current buffer the text that is under the heading "* Heading" in the file 'path-to-file/file.org'.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I don't have a direct solution.
I am using a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Keyboard-Macro.html#Basic-Keyboard-Macro) to copy the heading content from another org file.

In a similar link

```
[[file:file.org::*Heading][copy external content]]
```

I saved a keyboard macro,

```
F3 ;; to start defining the keyboard macro
C-c C-o ;; to open the file and point to Heading
C-c C-x M-w ;; to copy the subtree 
C-x 0 ;; to close the buffer and switch to the previous one
C-e ;; end of line
RET ;;
C-y ;; yank
F4 ;; end the macro definition
C-x C-k n ;; define a name for kb macro (session only)
```

In your .emacs configuration you can save the macro:

```
M-x insert-kbd-macro
```

Hope that can help!